# Random number between variables issue

Tags: javascript, random

I've seen the other examples on this site but I just can't get it to work.

I'm trying to generate a random number between 2 user input variables on a form. The numbers will always be positive numbers.

```
min = document.getElementById('min').value;
max = document.getElementById('max').value;
waitTimer = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

When min = 5 / max = 10, waitTimer is sometimes returning results like 2,  4 and 28 and so on.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did u try with direct writing `min = 5` and `max = 10` in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to convert the `.value` strings to numbers (I just used the `+` operator for the conversion in my jsFiddle).

When you convert them to numbers, it all works fine as you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/XF75E/

Comment: one query : `$('body')` also works similar to `$('document.body')`

Comment: @diEcho - I figure it's faster to pass the actual DOM element `document.body` rather than a string `'body'` that has to be parsed before it can then be converted to `document.body`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fiddle of this working. Make sure you are using `parseInt()`

http://jsfiddle.net/zAeR7/2/

You just need to put a number in each input and click off the input (or press tab) and it should update the random number.

Comment: It's very bad to call `parseInt()` without padding he 2nd argument (the radix) because `parseInt()` will guess the radix based on the leading characters it sees.  My jsFiddle just used the `+` operator which does not have this issue.